# Develop desktop application to update sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint

i want to update sharepoint list from desktop application. How can I do that ?

Comment: Next time....Please ask specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Client Object Model is a good option if your using SharePoint 2010 - but its not available for 2007.

Another option is using the Web Services - [Getting Started With SharePoint Web Services](http://www.infoq.com/articles/swanson-moss-web-services)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Client Object Model for .net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx).

[Here's a nice intro](http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/SharePoint-2010-Introducing-the-Client-Object-Model.aspx).

You will need these two dll's from a SharePoint server:

- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.Runtime.dll

Hope it helps!